# Migration jsp vers wicket

Tags: java, jsp, wicket

I am a beginner in wicket,
I did a jsp code migration to wicket,
I'm implementing the same method that reads and displays the log file,
of course, in the presentation layer, I use wicket components.
the problem is :
  with the jsp code I did not have a problem with the time out
with wicket when the file is large, the page load will be too long until the browser crashes.
is there a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess in JSP you use something like `<%@page buffer="xxxkb" autoFlush="true" %>`, so it doesn't construct the full response before start sending it to the browser.

In Wicket if you construct a Page then the whole Page should be assembled and the writing to the response starts after that.

So this could be the reason why you see something rendered with the JSP solution. But if the content is too big (i.e. the log file is too big) I'd expect that the browser will have problems with the JSP solution too, unless you unload old content (as virtual scrolling grids do).

To accomplish the same in Wicket you can use mounted resource instead of a page. This way you will be in control when to flush the generated response so far. But as I said above better think about a solution renders the page skeleton first and then with Ajax/WebSocket load the file content part by part. This way when you load the Nth part you may start removing the oldest part to offload the DOM renderer in the browser.